# JavaFX ScrollPane setEditable()

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I'm searching for a way to get my ScrollPane not editable but I don't want it to change its color. The problem is that `setDiasabled()` is changing the color.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any specific reasons for not using `setEditable()` on the controls instead of the layout?

Comment: Is there a setEditable method in the ScrollPane class, I guess there is none! setEditable is applicable for inputs only.

Comment: @TheWell There ain't. The OP either wants to remove editable functionality from few controls or doesn't want any user interaction & disable everything. I am trying to find which one is it ;)

Comment: Im using a dynamically amout of of CheckBoxes, my way to solve it was a list with all of them and diasable them with for(){}. This checkboxes are in the scroll pane. And i was looking for a smarter way to do this.

Comment: The checkboxes can't be directly in the `ScrollPane`: they must be in some other container that you place in the `ScrollPane`. Just call `setDisable(true)` on that container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
private void setBoxesEditable(boolean state)
{
    for (CheckBox checkBox : allBoxes) {
        checkBox.setDisable(!state);
        checkBox.setOpacity(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are setting the opacity you can easly prevent that!